# Using integer variable as key in underscore template

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

According to underscore's [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#template), it allows you to do string template/interpolation like below:

```
var compiled = _.template("hello: <%= name %>");
compiled({name: 'moe'});
// => "hello: moe"
```

Instead of using variable symbol like "name", I wonder if there is any way to use integer as the key? For example:

```
var compiled = _.template("hello: <%= 1 %>");
compiled({"1": 'moe'});
// => "hello: moe"
```

I gave it a try but underscorejs template evaluates it as a literal instead of variable, is there any way to do templating with underscore if the provided variable contains such integer key in it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not use an integer, you have to use a **valid variable** name, this means it can have an integer but it can not be only an integer.

Things that work are:

```
compiled = _.template("hello: <%= a1 %>");
console.log(compiled({a1: 'moe'}));

compiled = _.template("hello: <%= _1 %>");
console.log(compiled({_1: 'moe'}));


compiled = _.template("hello: <%= a %>");
console.log(compiled({a: 'moe'}));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BwHxv/309/